# JSF 2.0 - Way to step through each of the phases in a lifecycle with a debugger?

Tags: java, debugging, jsf, jsf-2

I'm writing custom JSF 2.0 components. Is there way to step through each of the phases in a lifecycle with a debugger?

Comment: What do you exactly want to to? You could write a `PhaseListener` that listens to all phases then look up the component in its methods.

Comment: A debugger can step through any Java code, and JSF is written in Java, so yes, of course you can. If you want a more specific answer, ask a more specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a breakpoint on the [`execute()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/lifecycle/Lifecycle.html#execute%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) method of the [`Lifecycle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/lifecycle/Lifecycle.html) implementation of your JSF implementation. It's there where each phase of the JSF lifecycle expect of the render response will be executed. To hook on render response as well, put another beakpoint on [`render()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/lifecycle/Lifecycle.html#render%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) method of the same `Lifecycle` implementation.

In Mojarra, the `Lifecycle` implementation is the `com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl` class. It's open source (so is MyFaces), you can download the source at the vendor's homepage such as http://javaserverfaces.java.net.